# how to change data in db from string to id - Rails, Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, yaml, rails-migrations

Hello I have maybe easy problem maybe not...

History: I wanted to replace **yaml** file with statuses to db(mysql) and i had in user table column: status. When i replacing logic to db i have created model Status, created table and configured relationship with user...

Describe problem: When i created status_id in user table i have 2 columns: "status" and "status_id". The column "status" is string and have a lot of string value for example "confirmed". How to (using seed migration with statuses) and fill the "status_id" column. I mean if "status" column have value "confirmed" i'd like to have in "status_id" column value: 1.

```
statuses table:
id name
1   confirmed
2   not confirmed
3   something else


Users table
id status           status_id
1  confirmed        empty
2  confirmed        empty
3  confirmed        empty
4  not confirmed    empty
5  not confirmed    empty
6  something else   empty
7  something else   empty
```

> User belongs_to :status
>
> Status has_many :users

---

> **question:** *Why i didnt just change name and type in "status" column on*
>   "status_id" with data type: "id"?
>
> **answer:** *Because i need to deploy it using capistrano to production
>   server and i cant losing data and remove data from status column.*

Answer (score 3):

Given the following (your) sample data:

```
create table statuses (id int, name char(20));
insert into statuses (id, name) values
    (1, 'confirmed'),
    (2, 'not confirmed'),
    (3, 'something else');

create table users (id int, status char(20), status_id int);
insert into users (id, status) values
    (1,'confirmed'),
    (2,'confirmed'),
    (3,'confirmed'),
    (4,'not confirmed'),
    (5,'not confirmed'),
    (6,'something else'),
    (7,'something else');

select * from users;
+------+----------------+-----------+
| id   | status         | status_id |
+------+----------------+-----------+
|    1 | confirmed      |      NULL |
|    2 | confirmed      |      NULL |
|    3 | confirmed      |      NULL |
|    4 | not confirmed  |      NULL |
|    5 | not confirmed  |      NULL |
|    6 | something else |      NULL |
|    7 | something else |      NULL |
+------+----------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This `update` statement updates the `status_id` column in `users` with the appropriate values from `statuses`:

```
update users u 
   set u.status_id=(select s.id from statuses s where u.status=s.name);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 7  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0

select * from users;
+------+----------------+-----------+
| id   | status         | status_id |
+------+----------------+-----------+
|    1 | confirmed      |         1 |
|    2 | confirmed      |         1 |
|    3 | confirmed      |         1 |
|    4 | not confirmed  |         2 |
|    5 | not confirmed  |         2 |
|    6 | something else |         3 |
|    7 | something else |         3 |
+------+----------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this is what you asked for, because my answer does neither involve ruby, yaml, nor rails.

Comment: OK...its correct but...I need this answer writed in ruby on rails...like using update_attribute or something similar. But for answer +1 :)

Comment: Ohh, thanks for the +1, but then I'm afraid you have to wait for other answers as I've no clue on how this would be done with rails.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a one-off data migration which can be handled in several different ways. One way is to write a one-off script or rake task which will update all the users.

some_task.rake

```
desc 'Add status id to existing users'

namespace :users do
  task assign_status: :environment do
    statuses = {}
    Status.all.each {|status| statuses[status.name] = status.id}
    User.all.each do |user|
      user.update_attribute(status_id: statuses[user.status])
    end
  end
end
```

If you have a lot of users, you may want to use [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) which is more performant as it uses batching. You may also want to add some kind of progress reporting in the rake task.

This approach allows you to test the task against a copy of your existing database.

Comment: you are almost there...but instead of creating rake task i found better way. Add Seed Migration and using sql (something like "execute") take all statuses (which are strings) and compare them with status table (like "confirmed" = "confirmed") and then use relationship to change status.name to status.id and push them to db. I have still no idea how to do that...but i know its easiest way and Open/Close principle will be maintained.

Comment: You asked for a way to do this with rails. I'm not sure using a seed file is the best way and I don't know if you'd want to change the column in the way you describe. Once you've completed your data changes, you could run a migration or a task to delete the status.name from user. However you will want to ensure that whatever approach you take allows future deploys of your app to different enviroments e.g. lets you run your migrations seamlessly.